# How to delete taxonomy term when a wordpress user is removed?

Tags: wp-query, functions, hooks, wpdb

i need to Delete wp_terms -> name field when a user is delete .

my requirement is admin needs to assign posts to specific users, that is admin need to add a post to user1 ,but user2 should not see that.for this i created a custom post and add taxonomy for that.And the terms are users Usernames .so i need to list the usernames of the users as terms in the taxonomy.when a new user is registered his username should updated in the wp_terms table also,so i will get the usernames as terms. this is working well ,now i need to delete the term from taxonomy when the user is removed.

i stucked here .please suggest some solution for this

what i have done is

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'yg_user_delete', 10, 1 );

function yg_user_delete( $user_id ) {

$user_info = get_userdata($user_id); $user_name = $user_info->user_login;



wp_delete_term( $user_name, 'user1', array() );

}
```

here 'user1' is my taxonomy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this with yours:

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'yg_user_delete', 10, 1 );

function yg_user_delete( $user_id ) {

    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id); 
    $user_name = $user_info->user_login;

    print_r($user_info);

    wp_delete_term( get_term_by('name', $user_name, 'user1')->term_id, 'user1', array() );

}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: when i delete the user the term is not deleting

Comment: when you are adding term, are slug and term name the same??

Comment: yes the code i have done for adding term when user created is

Comment: add_action( 'user_register', 'yg_user_registration', 10, 1 );

    function yg_user_registration( $user_id ) {

    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id); $user_name = $user_info->user_login;

    wp_insert_term( $user_name, 'user1', array() );

    }

Comment: edited the code and its okay now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80975/discussion-between-adarsh-and-siavash1991).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you have  a `custom_taxonomy` and the terms slugs of it correspond to the usernames..in  this case try

```
function yg_user_delete( $user_id ) {
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id); 
  $user_name = $user_info->user_login;

  wp_delete_term(get_term_by('slug', $user_name)->term_id,'custom_taxonomy');
}
```

Comment: yes ,when a wp user is removed the term should also be removed from the taxonomy

Comment: And what if get_term_by won’t find such term? Some error processing would be nice in there ;)

Comment: it will not happen .because when a new user is added, at that time only the new term will create by using  the username  of user.so the error will not come

Comment: but the code is not working

Comment: What is the custom taxonomy you use?

Comment: 'user1' is my custom taxonomy slug

Comment: @Adarsh of course it can happen... Errors occur and your should always process them. You can’t use some function and assume it will give you always one type of result, if it can give few other results... get_term_by function can return error and you should always process it...